# How to resize an image when stretched in canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have displayed an image on canvas.Below is the code.Is there any way to dynamically stretch or shrink image when the image is dragged by user in various directions? How to approach it?

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(new MyView(this));
     }

     public class MyView extends View
     {
         public MyView(Context context) 
         {
              super(context);
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
         {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Bitmap _scratch =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dog);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, 0, 0, null);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this also worked for stretching

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Or you can try this way

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Comment: I think I was unable to put it clearly. What I am asking is that if there is a way to dynamically stretch or shrink image when the image is dragged by user.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that in your question, thats Y i posted this answer